# Community user should give reason for making a post community wiki

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki

I noticed that one of my answers on superuser had been edited by the community user. Looking at the [history](https://superuser.com/revisions/5309/list) it just says "[made Community Wiki]". I'm left wondering why because it hasn't been edited and there are other answers to that question left before mine that haven't been turned to CW.

If the Community user always left a reason why a question had been changed to community wiki people wouldn't have to ask.

**Update:** it's been speculated that it was Community Wiki because the question was community wiki, which I accept, but if that was the case, and it was created initially as community wiki then **why was I [notified on my recent activity page](https://superuser.com/users/recent/772?StartDate=2009-07-16&EndDate=2009-07-16&Tab=Revisions) that there had been an edit?**

**Update:** happened again, but this time it's clearly because [the question](https://superuser.com/revisions/5757/list) was made community wiki which forced [my answer](https://superuser.com/revisions/5757/list) into community wiki without explaining why.

Answer (score 3):

A reason would have been nice for this question:

[Is 23,148,855,308,184,500 a magic number, or sheer chance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133581/is-23-148-855-308-184-500-a-magic-number-or-sheer-chance)

I'm still not sure why it was made CW by a moderator. It's a valid question, and is definitely programming related and not subjective at all really.

Comment: you know who's responsible. Ask a question.

Comment: probably because answers to that question are unlikely to be useful to anyone else in future.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a mod went in and turned yours to CW. In that case I would think it should be appropriate for the moderator to leave a comment explaining as such (as long as it is not blatantly obvious).

Comment: I thought it would state who the mod was if that's what happened. I'm sure I've seen "made CW by X" messages before.

Comment: Sam Hasler: I wouldn't be surprised if you are correct, but I have not noticed that behavior (granted I tend to catch questions very early and wikify them when needed, so I don't think it even shows up as a revision)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a moderator did anything in this case. When you post a question or answer as Community Wiki, the notes for the original revision are:

> [made Community Wiki]

Since you answered a Wiki question, your answer was made Wiki by default, and thus has that in its revision notes.

Comment: If it was created that way then why did I get notified about in my recent activity page as an edit?

Comment: I don't know, it's probably a bug. I noticed that too a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

You answered a CW question. That's how SO indicates that answer becomes CW. No one actually went it and did anything to your answer. The other answers were given while question hasn't been turned into CW. I have a question on here btw, [that advocates forcing all answers into cw once question was made CW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/force-answers-into-cw-after-question-has-been-made-cw).

Comment: If it was created that way then why did it appear on my recent activity page as an edit?

Comment: hm? where? here? http://superuser.com/users/772?tab=recent#sort-top I don't see anything.

Comment: not that recent activity; this one: (which no-one apart from me can see) http://superuser.com/users/recent/772?StartDate=2009-07-16&EndDate=2009-07-16&Tab=Revisions