# If a question becomes Community Wiki, are all answers switched to CW automatically as well?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I've just started reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602138/is-a-debugger-the-mother-of-all-evil) which (<strike>probably because of the many upvotes</strike>) is a community wiki question (if this is the right term for it).

Browsing through its answers, I see that all answers are marked community wiki as well (which makes sense, IMHO), except the accepted answer.

Is this because a CW question does not automatically force all answers to be CW as well? Or is it because there is not enough room on the physical page to display that it is CW as well?

**Edit**: I was wrong assuming that upvotes can make a question community wiki.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find one at the moment

Comment: I tried to find a duplicate myself, but couldn't find one.

Comment: This is the closest - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/force-answers-into-cw-after-question-has-been-made-cw - but it's not a duplicate.

Comment: For info, the number of votes don't make it CW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the answers to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/force-answers-into-cw-after-question-has-been-made-cw) and my own experience I think that the situation is:

a) If the OP makes the question CW or the question becomes CW due to the number of edits, no existing answers are converted to CW, but all new answers are automatically CW.

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/11741#11741) for what looks like a complete list of ways that a question can become CW.

b) If a moderator makes the question CW then all existing answers are converted to CW and all new answers are automatically CW.

Comment: Yes; you could extend "a" to include "it becomes CW automatically due to high activity", too

Comment: Auto-CW swith: SO/SF/M - 30 answers; SU - 15 answers.

Comment: Is this still true? In MetaSOes [a question](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4771/83) was marked as CW but the answer remains non-CW.