# Should non-CW answers to CW questions be eligible to gain rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki

I have just discovered secondhand that a non-CW answer to a CW question will still accumulate rep normally.  Is this by design, or is it an uncaught edge case?  Either way, is it a Good Idea?  The post that inspired this question is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/what-is-a-favorite-question-how-do-they-work); see the comments.  (EDIT: although I asked this question in a general way, I'm *primarily* interested in the case where this results from merging of questions.)

A discussion about a closely related topic was [held about a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/force-answers-into-cw-after-question-has-been-made-cw), but it doesn't seem that any consensus was ever reached, let alone officially blessed by a Valued Associate.  Also, I believe that that discussion was held before the "merging questions" capability existed.

EDIT 2: Hm, there seems to have been some confusion.  I wasn't asking whether this behavior *could* exist — an example is linked to in the post.  I was asking whether it was intentional and positive (as opposed to, say, a known but undesired side effect of implementing the "many edits → auto-CW" rule).  But the consensus — using that term loosely — seems to be "case by case basis, flag for a mod if you find a qualifying case."

Comment: You are correct, if someone posts non-cw answer to a normal question, it will remain as such after the question is converted to a CW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Originally, this was by design: every post could be made CW (or left non-CW) at its author's discretion.

Then the checkbox was defaulted to CW for answers composed to CW questions.

Finally, the checkbox was defaulted, disabled, and removed entirely for answers on CW questions. However, no change was made to force answers posted to non-CW questions into CW mode when the question itself changed to CW: the status of questions and answers remains independently tracked.

This largely reflects the way the purpose and use of CW has changed over the life of the site.

IMHO, *most* CW questions should force their answers into CW mode as well. Note that questions collecting more than 30 answers (15 on SU) will automatically drop into CW, *along with* all their answers... I recommend flagging for moderator attention if you find one that hasn't played out this way.

Comment: Ah, but if the question was manually wikied *before* hitting 30 answers, any existing non-wiki answers will not be auto-wikied.

Comment: @mmyers: whaaat... That's *still* not fixed?!

Comment: Not last I knew, anyway. There obviously aren't a lot of chances to test it.

Comment: @mmyers and Shog9, you could test it by edit-forcing [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163229/using-foo-and-bar-in-examples) into CW, as it has a whopping 45 answers due to merging but nothing was ever forced into CW. Adding another answer, perhaps a dummy one, would then reveal how this plays out. But it perhaps raises a bigger question of what to do with questions that reached 30+ answers by merging.

Comment: @ccomet: yeah, I screwed up that test by posting a new answer *first*... Oops, [try this one instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830/most-elegant-amusing-or-strange-code-one-liners).

Comment: You grabbed the one I was about to suggest. I perused all of them with `answers:30 wiki:0`, that one has the most non-author revisions already so it is the best candidate. I'll toss in an extra edit to remove the cobol tag.

Comment: @ccomet: Why `answers:30` and not `answers:29`? You don't want ones that are already past wiki length, you want one that can be forced to wiki with one more answer. Or am I missing something?

Comment: ...looks like I indirectly messed up the test by editing it. This caused it to go to the front page, where people promptly posted new responses to it. We're going to need a more controlled environment to test it with, or get a moderator to help with initially converting a question to CW (without applying it to all answers).

Comment: @mmyers I was grabbing all the old questions that are above 30 answers by virtue or merging or being beta questions, using `wiki:0` to aid in that endeavor. 29 technically works, but I was just using a search for "This should be CW" rather than "This is almost CW". Your search would provide a larger pool of candidates, naturally.

Comment: @ccomet: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101055/when-is-a-language-considered-a-scripting-language (it's actually somewhat of a specific question, so *maybe* less likely to pick up off-the-cuff answers)

Comment: Well, between when I left the office and when I arrived home, that question became CW, so I wasn't around to observe... did we get any data or did the test fall through again?

Comment: @ccomet: eh, someone replied before the question could be edited.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of CW is to make a question or answer editable to anyone who has 100+ reputation. Since its assumed that a possibly high number of people would edit a single post, no reputation is earned by the OP, it would not be fair.

That somehow turned into a shield to keep off topic or highly subjective questions open, "*Look, I'm not earning any rep for this at all ..*", or protect your reputation from down votes when posting something that might annoy people.

If you are providing a technical answer to a subjective question (not sure if that's possible, it might be though), you should earn reputation for doing so. If you want the majority of SO users to be able to edit your post, make it CW at the cost of gaining no reputation.

Otherwise, its up to *you* how you mark it. Beware, however, if answering an off topic or subjective question (off topic or subjectively), you may lose reputation unless you do give up rep by making it CW at a cost of letting the majority of SO users edit your post.

There is no 'rule' when it comes to that, just a sort of consensus in the community.

Answer (score 0):

Some questions become CW due to excessive editing.  This should not affect whether the existing answers should be CW, and it doesn't, so you will occasionally see CW questions with regular answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design to prevent gaming the system. Or maybe I should say reverse-gaming of the system. The idea is to stop random editors from being able to *prevent* answerers from gaining rep.

Since a question can easily get edited into CW mode (see my partial solution to the problem [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46078/quick-edits-force-a-badly-formatted-post-to-wiki-within-minutes/46083#46083)), it doesn't make sense for existing answers to be affected by that switchover.

There's currently a diamond mod function that can turn a question and all its answers into CW posts. If you see a question that should be "full CW," flag it for mod attention so they can take a look.