# My answer was switched from CW and I did not get any rep

Tags: support, reputation, community-wiki

[My answer here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12462/719) was switched from CW and I did not get any rep for it. (except for the accepted answer rep)

[Related site meta question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/564/719)

---

There is [nothing in the revision history](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/12462/revisions) to even suggest a CW ever happened even.

Comment: Did you the recalc?

Comment: @Chichiray yep. to no avail. the `+60` rep just is **not** there....

Comment: Did you get upvotes _after_ the change?

Comment: @Oded no I did **not**. (well not that I know of).

Comment: Well, that would probably explain it. Upvotes that happened during the CW period are CW upvotes, not yours...

Comment: @Oded that makes no sense. It was switched back. it should have a fallback to me. I would understand if it was the other way, but it was not.

Comment: I believe you only get the rep for upvotes you got when the post was not marked as CW.

Comment: @Oded do you have any documentation to that fact?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4236/140505

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA _It was switched back. it should have a fallback to me._ would it be right to assume that you'd agree to **get all the CW-period downvotes** in this case, too?

Comment: @Oded -- that is the **other way around**....

Comment: @gnat yes, yes I should  get all of the votes no matter what they were. ^_^

Comment: Related thing [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status) - but I don't really understand Jeff Atwood's comment on his answer, apart from the fact that this type of thing is quite rare.

Comment: It makes sense though. Votes are easier given away if the post is CW.

Comment: @Chichiray not on every site..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the rundown [in the FAQ on CW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), these points seem to indicate that you shouldn't necessarily expect any reputation for the post (on votes cast by peers within the period of it being CW):

- Community Wiki posts are owned by the Community User, not by any individual user.
- Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's reputation.
- The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their post entered community mode.
- Rollbacks do not reverse any of the Community Wiki mode calculations.

Perhaps the FAQ needs to be updated to be more explicitly clear on that, but if you get reputation up to the point of it being made Community Wiki then you should expect to gather reputation from the point that it was non-Community Wiki (which is redundant now, since there is no such thing, the post is just *yours* again (*but not votes, Community owns those given*)), but **not** to gain reputation of votes cast *throughout* that period (as in a backlog).

Comment: Ahhh I see. `Rollbacks do not reverse any of the Community Wiki mode calculations.` <-- from the answer.

Comment: Forgot to add that item, thanks, I'll edit it in.